# gcc: warning: 'used' attribute ignored

Tags: c, gcc

I'm compiling my program with -O2 flag and I see that the attribute for a variable is ignored. Why is this and how can I force it to accept the attribute?

```
extern const int my_var __attribute__((used)); // but my_var is not actually 
                                               // used in this file, but I'd 
                                               // like it to be included in 
                                               // the symbol table

warning: 'used' attribute ignored
```

Answer (score 6):

`__attribute__((__used__))` only makes sense on `static` object or function *definitions*, and tells the compiler to emit the definition even if it seems not to be referenced at all, in which case it would normally be optimized out entirely. Objects defined with external linkage will never be optimized out (except possibly in whole-program mode or by the linker/LTO). But your usage is not even a definition; it's a declaration of an external object.

If your goal really is to force your object file to contain a reference to this external symbol even though it's not used, you could do something like:

```
extern const int my_var;
static const int *const dummy __attribute__((__used__)) = &my_var;
```

This creates a (useless) reference to `my_var` that can never be optimized out.